# how to reuse the same set of code for 2 packages

Tags: ssis

i have 2 ssis packages which uses the same query( with minor difference in the query for package1 and package2) and gives out 2 extracts **sample1.csv and sample2.csv**.

Instead of using two packages, i want to use only single package to fetch the extracts parallely for this scenario.

By running sinle job, i want to extract sample1.csv and sample2.csv at a time.

In both my packages, i have used temp tables in execute sql task, so in dataflow task i have taken script component to get the columns names and data.

I have attached sample query result output [image: Package1 output extract]

[image: Package2 output extract]

image one shows the query result i have used in package1. And image 2 shows the query result i have used in package2.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you want to import sample1.csv and sample2.csv, and use one package for this import?

Comment: yes, but i dont want to keep two DFT's one for package1 and another for package2.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. Solution is as follows:

1. Create a table ("Run") in SQL Server containing an ID column, a Query column and a Destination column
2. Create one record per "run" (i.e. per existing package), with the different queries in the Query column
3. Create a parent package with an Execute SQL Task to query the Run table, return all the required queries and put the output into an object variable
4. Add a for each enumerator to loop through the records returned, mapping the Query column to a Query variable and the Destination column to a Destination variable
5. Inside the for each enumerator, add an execute package task, pointing to your existing "child" package
6. In the child package, add another Query variable and set up a package configuration to grab the Parent's Query Variable. Do the same for Destination
7. Amend the data source in your child package to use a sql command from variable and point it to the Query variable
8. Amend the file manager used in the Child package destination to use an expression that builds the filepath/name using the destination variable

Note, this only works as long as each query returns exactly the same number of columns with the same datatype and data length. If not, you'll get all sorts of metadata errors.

This above could be improved upon by creating a stored procedure or user defined function in the SQL Server database to centralise the queries, and just store granular parameters in the Run table.